# mysql fulltext search in boolean mode

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I want to search the database using mysql's fulltext index using multiple search terms:

```
SELECT description FROM `products` WHERE match(name, description) against('*ana* *apple*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I want the above query to return the following records, but it wont work:

```
babana pie
applet
fried bananas
juicy apples
```

Is my query ok?

Comment: What happens? Do you get any hits? Too many? Too few?

Comment: @Pekka when running the query only the apple related records are returned

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into the fulltext's restriction that words appearing in more than a set % of the records are considered "noise" and ignored. Both 'banana' and 'apple' appear in 50% of your sample records, so are most likely not good matches. Try adding some other fruits into your test data and search for something that's more "rare".

Comment: it says here that when using boolean mode mysql ignores stopwords http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449431/mysql-full-text-stopwords-problem/4449780#4449780

Comment: @marcos this is not a stopword issue. This could be the reason

Comment: just added a bunch of data to the table, the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

You will get only apple related Records this is because wildcard at before a word

> (eg:*ana)

and for a phrase

> (eg:"apple ban"*)

is not supported in MySQL FTS.It will be simply ignored if wildcard is given before a word and for the phrase case error will be returned.